# Не запускается gunicorn через supervisor

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, gunicorn, supervisord

Логи gunicorn'a
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфиг supervisor
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если запускать gunicorn через bash скрипт, то он прекрасно работает. Видимо какая-то проблема в конфиге supervisor'a

start_gunicorn.sh
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну покажите ваш скрипт start_gunicorn.sh

Comment: добавь в вопрос и с форматированием. Понять скрипт в виде одной длинной колбасы в комментариях невозможно

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Но почему скриншотом?

Comment: В целом, ваша проблема вообще ни разу не уникальна https://www.google.com/search?q=gunicorn+exit+status+3

Comment: Мне нужно передать переменные окружения?